# Is there a way to run Nightwatch automation under different IP

Tags: javascript, proxy, ip, nightwatch.js

As the title says, are there anyway to run nightwatch under different IP ? I want to run test cases for my web that test if user could login from certain IP.

Are the any NW settings/configuration file that i can edit to achieve this ? Because I also want to run this script on Jenkins as well